# Connection to database in a managed thread, Debug values doesn't appear in Tomcat console or logs

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot

I am facing this trouble for a long time now without accessing the debug logs of the managed Threads in my Spring boot application when run on Tomcat. All the logs appear when run on the Eclipse/STS.

In Tomcat logs, I can only see the main Tread Logs.

I am connection to a database through JDBC and this is happening in a separate thread. I tried to follow the log configuration documentation but none of them helps to get the debug logs of these threads. So I do not actually  see the exact problem of what is causing the connection to fail.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. I tried with the following logback.xml

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
       <!-- <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
           <Target>System.out</Target> <encoder> <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p 
           %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern> </encoder> </appender> <logger name="com.biscoind" 
           additivity="false" level="TRACE"> <appender-ref ref="stdout" /> </logger> 
           <root level="debug"> <appender-ref ref="stdout" /> </root> -->
       <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
       <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" />
   </configuration>
   ```
2. When that did not resolve the issue I removed this file and see if by default, if it logs all the treads. But it did not.
3. So, I added the following configurations to the application.properties

   ```
   logging.level.org.springframework.web:TRACE
   logging.level.org.hibernate:ERROR
   ```

   Then It seemed to me that this is only logging out the above namespaces, I again added

   ```
   debug=true
   logging.level.org.springframework.web:DEBUG
   logging.level.org.hibernate:DEBUG
   ```

   Tried and it did not work.
4. I added my namespaces also and tried as follwing,

   ```
   debug=true
   logging.level.com.mydomain:DEBUG
   logging.level.org.springframework.web:DEBUG
   logging.level.org.hibernate:DEBUG
   ```

That did not work also, I am now confused on the what should I do with the config relative to logging to make the logs to appear for the tread executions.

Irrespective of the treads, because of the property `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` it logs the queries that are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a problem with the threads at all. The application was working correctly in the development environment. The problem was in the deployment environment.

It turned out to be a Java version miss-match with the jar files and the JVM version. The jars were build using Java 8 and it was running on Java 7 JVM.

When the JMV was changed to Java-8. It worked fine. So Next time I will be more careful with the version mismatch.